# Custom UITableViewCell data repeating when scrolled

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm using custom tableview cells. I've 2 sections, first is a custom cell which contains a dynamic height textview and second section custom cell contains labels with firstrow having StartDate and secondrow having EndDate. When a row in second section(DateCell) is selected a date picker is shown which is in a cell of type DatePickerCell.
Both StartDate and EndDate rows use custom cell of type DateCell.

The problem is when tableview is scrolled the same data is appearing in both StartDate and EndDate. 
I'm loading the cells from storyboard so the cells will not be nil.
I'm using different reuseidentifiers for StartDate and EndDate but still the problem exists.

Also, can anyone suggest what should be done in prepareForReuse method in this case.

Please find the code below.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) ->Int{
if section == 1 {
        if isDatePickerVisible == true {
            return 3
        }
        return 2
 }
 return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var identifier = ""
    switch indexPath.section {
        case 0 : identifier = kTextViewCellID
        case 1 :
            if datePickerIndexPath == indexPath && isDatePickerVisible == true   {
                identifier = kDatePickerCellID
            }
            else if indexPath.row == 0 {
                identifier = kStartDateCellID
            }
            else {
                identifier = kEndDateCellID
            }
        default: identifier = ""
    }

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
    if let c = cell as?  TextCell {
        //do something
    }
    //Both StartDate and EndDate are DateCell type
    else if let c = cell as?  DateCell {
        c.dateLable.text =  … //some text
        c.dateValue?.text = … // some date in string format
    }
    else if let c = cell as? DatePickerCell {
       //show DatePicker
    }
    return cell
}


class DateCell : UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var dateValue: UITextField?
@IBOutlet weak var dateLable: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

func setSomeColor() {
    dateValue?.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
}

func clearDateValue (clear: Bool) {
    //...
}
override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
}
}
```

Comment: By a quick look at it I'd say should be useful to see how you get the data from which you populate the cells labels etc.

Comment: You've only shown us "..." for the part where you assign the date to the label. That seems like a significant part of this puzzle.

Comment: Previous comments are right, especially since the condition (`as? DateCell`) you use before configuring the cell is insufficient to distinguish between the Start and End date cells.

Answer (score 0):

You make changes on "c" variable, but return "cell" variable. You should return "c" variable or make changes on "cell" variable.

Comment: Because the cell is an NSObject (a class), c will point to the same object as cell, and so that part of this code isn't the problem.